# jQuery send GET and POST parameters simultaneously at AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

How to send GET and POST parameters with jQuery AJAX request simultaneously?

I am trying to add  `do=ajax&id=" + ID` to `url`, but as the result request sanded only to `sss.php` without query string (get part). thanks.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sss.php?do=ajax&id=" + ID ,
    type: "post",
    data: "ddd=sss",
    // callback handler that will be called on success
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    },
    // callback handler that will be called on error
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.log(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: try to use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`

Comment: @defuz: He/she *is* using `post`, for all intents and purposes. [`post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is just a convenience wrapper for `type: "post"` requests.

Comment: For me your solution is working. It should work for you too. Go and check your Chrome Network Console to see what request was sent to server.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I understand that, but as far as I can remember, I have a similar example to work correctly, the only difference that I see, I used the method `post`. Maybe there is some differences. This is just my guess, not an answer.

Comment: Query string goes with `get` not with `post`, because `post` passes everything transparently, AFAIK.

Comment: @Dobiatowski I am using firefox with httpfox plugin (log) and I see absolutely clear that method is post, `ddd=sss` sended, but `do=ajax&id=XX` not. :( server also send the answer that "no id"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're getting an observational error, or seeing a server-side rather than jQuery problem. When I do a post [like this](http://jsbin.com/eduzif/1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://jsbin.com/eduzif/1?foo=bar",
  type: "post",
  data: "baz=doh",
  success: function() {
    display("Done, look at your console's network tab");
  }
});
```

...both the query string and POST data are sent to the server. It's easy to check this if you use a modern browser like Chrome or Firefox and look in the Network tab of the console after triggering the post. In my case:

[image: Image showing post with both query string and form data]

*(You can ignore that the server above replied with 403; JSBin doesn't allow POST, but that doesn't affect what we see in the request going to the server.)*

So the answer here is: Double-check how you're getting the data server-side. The parameters in the URL ("GET" style parameters) are available as query string parameters (part of the URL); the "POST" style parameters are available as "form" data (e.g., the body of the response). Depending on the server-side technology you're using, usually there are different ways to retrieve GET (query string) parameters vs. POST (form data / body) parameters.

Comment: thanks, rechecked, copy&past code and seems now it work. does not know whats was wrong with the first version of my code :( thanks