# Can AWS API Gateway support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with body and query string parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, query-string, x-www-form-urlencoded

Numerous services can accept query string parameters in the URL when a `POST` request is made with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and other parameters in the body, but it seems AWS API Gateway cannot while also accepting query string parameters.

When I call the AWS API Gateway with a `POST` Mapping Template for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and query string URL parameters (with a Lambda function), I get the following error:

```json
{
  "message":"When Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
    URL cannot include query-string parameters (after '?'):
    '/prod/webhook?inputType=wootric&outputType=glip&url=...'"
}
```

Here is an example cURL:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://{myid}.execute-api.{myregion}.amazonaws.com/prod/webhook? \
inputType=wootric&outputType=glip&url=https://hooks.glip.com/webhook/ \
11112222-3333-4444-5555-666677778888' \
-d "@docs/handlers/wootric/event-example_response-created.txt" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -v
```

The specific goal is to get a Wootric webhook event posted to a Lambda function using a URL with query string parameters.

You can get the code here:

https://github.com/grokify/chathooks

The Wootric event body file is here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grokify/chathooks/master/docs/handlers/wootric/event-example_response-created.txt

The GitHub issue is here:

https://github.com/grokify/chathooks/issues/15

The error message seems pretty definitive but I wanted to ask:

1. Is there a workaround to configure an API Gateway to support both?
2. Is there a standards-based reason why AWS would not support this or is this just a design decision / limitation?

If there's no solution to this, is there a good lightweight solution other than deploying a hosted server solution like Heroku. Also, do other cloud services support this with their API gateway + cloud functions, like Google?

Some examples showing support for both:

- jQuery example: [jQuery send GET and POST parameters simultaneously at AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680522/jquery-send-get-and-post-parametrs-simultaneously-at-ajax-request)
- C# example: [Accessing query string variables sent as POST in HttpActionContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201395/accessing-query-string-variables-sent-as-post-in-httpactioncontext)

Comment: Did You resolve this somehow?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I got the point in question correctly, but if you want to access the request body that is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`(or anything, actually) in your Lambda function, you should use `LAMBDA_PROXY` request integration type (aka tick "Use Lambda Proxy integration" checkbox) when creating a method for your resource. Then you can access the request body in `event.body` field as a plain text in your lambda function and parse it manually.

Comment: check box "Use Lambda Proxy integration" in api gateway method helped for .net 6 web api.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, with a 3rd party provider using web hooks. It turns out that my provider is transforming the url path from `UPPERCASE` to `LOWERCASE`. Example the endpoint should be `apigateway.com/dev/0bscur3dpathRANDOM` instead `apigateway.com/dev/0bscur3dpathRANDOM`. You get the point.

Answer (score -2):

Please set the request property as "Content-Type", "application/json" for your HttpURLConnection like below
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");